# The csv Export included requested data from database along with the php code of the module calling it

Tags: php

I'm trying to export data to a csv file from selected records in the database. While the export did work (I do see the selected records in the csv file), the entire PHP code from the calling module was ALSO exported into the CSV file. My question is how do I NOT export PHP code into the CSV file, please?

```
$select = "SELECT * from my_table";
$export = mysqli_query($conn, $select);  
$fields = mysqli_num_fields($export);

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{$header .= mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i)->name . "\t";}

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $export ) )
{   $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                  
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
            {$value = "\t";}
    else
            {$value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
         $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            }
    $line .= $value;
    }
$data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{$data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=database_export.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";
```

This is an extract of what gets dumped out. You see some php code and then you see the actual data. But the real csv file has the ENTIRE PHP code followed by the actual data from the table. I have never seen this happen before.

```
</td><tr><td width=50><a class="btn-success" href="invoiced_read.php?id=12">Read</a> <td>00000</td><td>Svc</td><td>12/13/18</td><td>CHICAGO, IL</td><td>123</td><td></td><td>Y</td><td>Employee-name</td><td>Invoiced</td><td>12<td width=250>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="12"
                                      </td>                      </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
                You have selected the following 2 option(s): <br/>location_num = 11111<br>row_id = 481<br>-----------<br>location_num = 06704<br>row_id = 480<br>-----------<br><br/><b>Note :</b> <span>action if values shown.</span>                                                                                                                                     
"123"   "8" "11111" "Street Address"    "City-Name" "State" "Bob-firstname" "Smith-last-name"   "2019-04-10"    "S"     "3"         "SHAMWOW"   "15.00" "1500"  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel erat cursus, porttitor augue non, dapibus turpis. In commodo facilisis velit, blandit condimentum magna laoreet at. Duis quis gravida erat. Fusce commodo suscipit eros eget condimentum. Donec libero purus, varius vulputate sem at, convallis ultricies dui. Vivamus nec egestas ex. Mauris faucibus nisl nisl, ac accumsan ipsum mattis quis. Sed quis augue a sapien sodales iaculis vel sed diam.

Suspendisse ut nunc in erat cursus interdum. Vestibulum laoreet gravida felis et sagittis. Aliquam sollicitudin feugiat odio ac consectetur. Morbi iaculis turpis nisi, ut feugiat dui vestibulum ac. Aliquam ultrices enim sapien, vitae ultrices nulla iaculis sit amet. Curabitur quis nisl arcu. Maecenas elementum imperdiet tincidunt. Nullam sodales dui ut ornare tincidunt. Maecenas vitae urna ullamcorper, hendrerit mi nec, feugiat ex. Phasellus placerat mauris eget enim commodo, quis faucibus ex sollicitudin. Sed eget pharetra nibh"             "Y"         "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "0.00"  "99"    "N" "N" "N"

        </form>
```

Comment: Because you should __stop__ your script after outputting csv data.

Comment: You don't need all that code, just call [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Comment: I used fputscv as suggested but I get the same results. I have not been able to resolve this issue since June. Any input would be appreciated, please:

     $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
     fputcsv($file, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));
     $query = 'SELECT   * TABLE';
     if ($rows = mysqli_query($conn, $query))
     { while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
 { fputcsv($file, $row);}       }
     }